# Spring Webflux Non-Blocking Dependent Resource Calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I am using Spring Webflux and Spring Data MongoDB Reactive.
In my REST Controller I am trying to get all objects of a kind (e.g. all bikes of a brand) from the database (MongoDB).
My current implementation looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/bybrand/{brandId}")
public Flux<Bike> bikesByBrand(@PathVariable(value = "brandId") String brandId) {
    return bikeRepository.findByBrand( //returns a Flux<Bike>
            brandRepository.findById(brandId) //returns a Mono<Brand>
                    .block() //returns a Brand
    );
}
```

To stay in the reactive pattern I want to avoid the block() call. I tried diverse combinations of map() and doOnSuccess() but didn't find the right way to do what I want to do.
Examples or tutorials I found online did not cover the use case of using dependent calls to the database.
How can I avoid using block() here and what would be the gold standard for accessing the database with a dependent previous call?

Another approach of mine would be the following.

```
brandRepository.findById(brandId)
            .doOnSuccess(brand -> bikeRepository.findByBrand(brand));
```

But I can't find a way to finally return the result of the lambda function (the Flux of Bike) in the superior method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flatMapMany

```
return brandRepository.findById(brandId).flatMapMany(bikeRepository::findByBrand)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
Could you provide an example in case I need to do more consecutive calls like that?
Would i be doing something like brandRepository.findById(brandId).flatMapMany(...).flatMapMany(...)?

Comment: Yeah , you only need `flatMapMany` if converting from Mono to Flux though, otherwise just use `flatMap`